# При докеризации .NET приложения с tor не отвечает хост

Tags: c#, .net, docker

После развертывания .NET приложения, создается Onion, но происходит редирект на HTTPS

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  service2:
    container_name: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}service2
    image: service2
    hostname: service2
    ports:
      - "5003:5004"
    networks:
      - api2
    environment:
      USER: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}service2
      PASSWORD: password
      DB: db
    volumes:
      - ./seed.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/seed.sql
      - pgdata:/var/lib/service2/data
    restart: unless-stopped

  tor:
    image: service:latest
    links:
      - service
    volumes:
      - tor-keys:/var/lib/tor/hidden_service/
    networks:
      - api
    environment:
        BAR_TOR_SERVICE_HOSTS: '80:2000'
        BAR_TOR_SERVICE_VERSION: '3'
    secrets:
      - secret
    restart: always

  service:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}service
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: App/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "200:80"
    networks:
      - api
      - api2
    depends_on:
      - "service2"
    environment:
      CONNECTION_STRING: TestConnection
      CONNECTION_STRING2: TestConnection2

volumes:
    data:
    tor-keys:
        driver: local

networks:
    api:
      driver: bridge
    api2: 
      external: 
        name: api2name   
secrets:
    secret:
        file: ./private_key_bar_v3
```